# The chart.js zoom and pan plugin is not working in WKWebView

Tags: swiftui, chart.js

I added the zoom and pan functionality to a graph.
This works in Chrome and Safari. But when embedded in a SwiftUI WKWebview the entire graph zooms as if it is an image. I do not get the proper axis scaling.
I basically followed this tutorial to add the zoom. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUzVVPK1Nks&ab_channel=ChartJS

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js" integrity="sha512-UXumZrZNiOwnTcZSHLOfcTs0aos2MzBWHXOHOuB0J/R44QB0dwY5JgfbvljXcklVf65Gc4El6RjZ+lnwd2az2g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/1.2.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js" integrity="sha512-klQv6lz2YR+MecyFYMFRuU2eAl8IPRo6zHnsc9n142TJuJHS8CG0ix4Oq9na9ceeg1u5EkBfZsFcV3U7J51iew==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div id="container" style="position: relative; height:95vh; width:95vw">
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
     </div>
 
    <script>

        //var incomingData = __@data__;
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 500);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(158,200,62,1)');   
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(188,190,50,1)');
 
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
 
            data: {
                labels: ["5:30 PM","5:45 PM","6:00 PM","6:15 PM","6:30 PM","6:45 PM","7:00 PM","7:15 PM","7:30 PM","7:45 PM","8:00 PM","8:15 PM","8:30 PM","8:45 PM","9:00 PM","9:15 PM","9:30 PM","9:45 PM","10:00 PM","10:15 PM","10:30 PM","10:45 PM","11:00 PM","11:15 PM","11:30 PM","11:45 PM","12:00 AM","12:00 AM","12:15 AM","12:30 AM","12:45 AM","1:00 AM","1:15 AM","1:30 AM","1:45 AM","2:00 AM","2:15 AM","2:30 AM","2:45 AM","3:00 AM","3:15 AM","3:30 AM","3:45 AM","4:00 AM","4:15 AM","4:30 AM","4:45 AM","5:00 AM","5:15 AM","5:30 AM","5:45 AM","6:00 AM","6:15 AM","6:30 AM","6:45 AM","7:00 AM","7:15 AM","7:30 AM","7:45 AM","8:00 AM","8:15 AM","8:30 AM","8:45 AM","9:00 AM","9:15 AM","9:30 AM","9:45 AM","10:00 AM","10:15 AM","10:30 AM","10:45 AM","11:00 AM","11:15 AM","11:30 AM","11:45 AM","12:00 PM","12:15 PM","12:30 PM","12:45 PM","1:00 PM","1:15 PM","1:30 PM","1:45 PM","2:00 PM","2:15 PM","2:30 PM","2:45 PM","3:00 PM","3:15 PM","3:30 PM","3:45 PM","4:00 PM","4:15 PM","4:30 PM","4:45 PM","5:00 PM"],
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor : gradient, // Put the gradient here as a fill color
                    label: 'Temp',
                    data: [21.62,21.54,21.66,21.39,23,22.31,21.18,21.12,28.18,22.1633333333333333,20.66,20.18,19.7266666666666667,19.35,32.04,30.9533333333333333,33.18,31.9733333333333333,43.035,32.6225,31.7033333333333333,48.32,33.58,33.64,22.37,20.9,20.56,20.56,20.43,20.39,20.25,20,19.87,19.68,19.62,19.5,19.355,19.18,19.06,19,18.87,18.79,18.68,18.68,18.62,18.56,18.5,18.385,18.25,18.12,18,17.91,17.81,17.75,17.62,17.5,17.5,17.5,17.5,18.43,18.68,18.85,19.12,19.25,19.31,19.37,19.43,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,19.6,19.68,19.81,19.87,19.9533333333333333,20,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,22.18,22.37,22.31],
                    borderColor: '#9ec83e',
                    borderWidth: '1',
                    fill: true,
                 }]
            },
 
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    legend:{
                     display: false,
                    },
                    zoom: {
                        limits: {
                            x: {min: 0, max: 400, minRange: 50},
                            y: {min: 0, max: 200, minRange: 50}
                        },            
                        pan: {
                            enabled: true,
                            mode: 'xy',
                        },
                        zoom: {
  
                            wheel: {
                                enabled: true,
                            },
                            pinch: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            mode: 'xy',
                        }
                    }
                },

                maintainAspectRatio: false,

 
     animation: {
         duration: 0, // general animation time
     },
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        radius: 0
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        grid: {
                            display:false
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        grid: {
                            display:false
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            autoSkip: true,
                            maxTicksLimit: 4
                        }
                    }
                },
                
 
            }
 
        });

         Chart.register(zoomPlugin);
 

    </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried the following in Swift

```
wkWebview.scrollView.delegate = self

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```